# When I start my PC it freeze but a few times. How can I fix that?

Tags: freeze, troubleshooting

It's been a while, I've tried many things like swapping my PSU or changing my motherboard's battery, but nothing has changed. I've formatted many times since nothing has improved. My guess is turning on a hardware issue, but I don't know what component is causing this probllem.

My computer behaves like an old car battery that has a hard time starting the engine at winter. First my computer freezes after 3 seconds, then I press restart button. It's still freezing, but one minute after, then I press restart button. And sometimes the 4th time, but after that the computer is good for the day.

Every time I have this annoying ritual with my computer. Do you have any clue how I could fix the problem?

I will show the name of every hardware component in my computer, but since I've changed the GPU and PSU and nothing has changed.

- GPU: GTX 1070 (most recent)
- CPU: AMD 8350FX octa core (recent)
- RAM: 16GB (most recent)
- mobo: MSI 970 Gaming AMD+3 (not changed)
- Windows 64-bit

Comment: An elusive hardware problem is best handled by the repair-shop.

Answer (score 0):

The CPU could be over heating, causing it to thermal throttle and lock up. Some things to consider:

- How long have you used the CPU
- How long have you used the CPU cooler
- Is the cooler sufficient in proportion to the CPU's core count and more importantly clock rate
- How long has it been since you first applied thermal paste, consider replacing it

Comment: The CPU is 3 y old and the cooling fan setup 2y. I got 4 fans plus a huge cool master aluminium grid. Is that possible CPU has failed because he has to much cooled down? I could provide a picture if that could help.

Comment: No, temperature being too low is rarely a problem for electronics. it would have to be sub zero which it obviously isn't. I suppose given the new condition and high quality of the set up this rules out the possibility of thermal issues..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a few years ago with my old computer. I got it to a repair shop and they told me that a problem with the PSU had damaged one of the motherboard chips (I don't recall what it was). So they swapped the PSU and the chip and it fixed the problem.